# Set height to Row in Jetpack Compose equivalent to wrap_content in xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-row

I have this row with two buttons and one divider.
I had set the weight so the buttons can have the same width.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
    .height(300.dp)
) {
    Button(
        stringResource(id = R.string.ha_topos_button_description),
        Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
    Divider(whichType = "vertical")
    Button(
        stringResource(id = R.string.ha_gyms_button),
        Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
}
```

If I don't set the `.height(300.dp)` property to the Row, it disappears. I don't want to set any hardcoded height, I just want the row to have its "`wrap_content`" height.
How can I do it on Compose???

Comment: Is this a custom composable? `Divider(whichType = "vertical")`

Comment: @Abhimanyu yes, it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `wrapContentHeight` to have the row wrap to the content's height:

```
Row(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .padding(horizontal = 5.dp)
    .wrapContentHeight()
) {
    Button(
        stringResource(id = R.string.ha_topos_button_description),
        Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
    Divider(whichType = "vertical")
    Button(
        stringResource(id = R.string.ha_gyms_button),
        Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
}
```

Comment: woow it was quite simple and never thought that. I was trying a lot of difficult things ahah thanks a lot :D